# why are my database updates not loading without a refresh

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I am using angular with MySQL via php.  When I attempt to add to the db, it adds, but I have to click refresh on the browser to see the results.

I feel like this is the real benefit of angular, but I'm also very new to angular and MySQL for that matter, so I really don't know where I'm going wrong or how to make this work correctly.  It seems to be all my database calls.

Just to clear up, I'm intiliazing bootstrap, angular, and jquery on a page above and using ng-include.

Thanks for anyone out there who can point me in the right direction.

-html

```
<div class="widget-box" id="recent-box" ng-controller="ideasController">
    <div class="widget-header header-color-blue">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4 class="bigger lighter"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>&nbsp;Idea MANAGER</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-body ">
        <form id="newIdeaForm" class="add-idea">
        <div class="form-actions">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment" ng-model="ideaInput" placeholder="Add New Idea" >
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="addIdea(ideaInput)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New Idea</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>


        <div class="idea">
            <div style="width: 80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                <table class="table table-hover"> 
                    <tbody> 
                        <tr ng-repeat="idea in ideas | orderBy:'idea'"> 
                            <td>{{idea.IDEA}} <a ng-click="deleteIdea(idea.ID)" style="float:right;"><button class="btn btn">Delete</button></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-php

```
//addIdea.php

    <?php 
    require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
    if(isset($_GET['idea'])){
    $task = $_GET['idea'];
    $status = "0";
    $created = time();
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ideas(idea,status,created_at)  VALUES ('$idea', '$status', '$created')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    ?>

//getIdea.php

    <?php 
    require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
    $status = '%';
    if(isset($_GET['status'])){
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    }
    $query=mysql_query("select ID, IDEA, STATUS from ideas where status like '$status' order by status,id desc") or die(mysql_error());

    # Collect the results
    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }

    # JSON-encode the response
    echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
    ?>
```

-js

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ideasController', function($scope, $http) {
  getIdea(); // Load all available ideas 
  function getIdea(){  
  $http.get("ajax/getIdea.php").success(function(data){
        $scope.ideas = data;
       });
  };
  $scope.addIdea = function (idea) {
    $http.get("ajax/addIdea.php?idea="+idea).success(function(data){
        getIdea();
        $scope.ideaInput = "";
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the page or the section of the page to pull the new information from the database. You can user [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to reload the page via your addIdea.php.

```
   header('Location: thispage.html');
```

You can reload the page following the `INSERT` and the new data will be in the table.

```
    <?php 
    require_once 'db.php'; // The mysql database connection script
    if(isset($_GET['idea'])){
    $task = $_GET['idea'];
    $status = "0";
    $created = time();
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ideas(idea,status,created_at)  VALUES ('$idea', '$status', '$created')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
      header('Location: idea.html');
    ?>
```

Comment: $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ideas(idea,status,created_at)  VALUES ('$idea', '$status', '$created')") or die(mysql_error());
header('location: idea.html');

Comment: I added it, however it doesn't seem to refresh, I still have to manually click refresh within the browser.

Comment: @MVC_Future_Guru My php is not super sharp but you might need to use single quotes instead of double quotes around the Location.

Comment: it does, I'd wondered about the single quotes and changed them as well, but then I realized that status is set to "0", so either that's wrong as well or the quotes are the issue. No worries, I'll keep trudging away.  Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: Could you possible have it tied to your form instead? 

 <form method="post" action=" " onSubmit="window.location.reload()"> Good luck I hope to take a look again when I have a chance.

Comment: I wasn't using posts with the form however.